# Cisco AP's ignoring option 43 offered via infoblox as the dhcp server

Tags: dhcp, capwap, cisco-wlc

I have an issue with option 43 , the AP's (cisco )are learning  option 43 when  cisco switch is configured as the  DHCP server but AP's are ignoring the option 43 when infoblox is configured as the  DHCP server. do any one  have came across similar issue !

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the Cisco WLAn Controller has enabled DHCP option for the Access point.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @hertitu as the author of [the question you referenced](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2122/775), I can affirm that this is a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 1):

*Option 43* is different from others DHCP options, you can re-define internal length or sub options. In **INFOBLOX** (as you can read on the admin guide pag 803) you have to put hexadecimal value divided by colon ":"

Something like:

> 04:0c:12:34:0b:12

Comment: I tried different ways including the one you said, but no luck. Even took the packet capture on AP uplink , could see the option 43 from infoblox advertised , but the AP's are ignoring just the opt 43.

Comment: Pay attention, option 43 has different structure, inside the typical option value it contains another level: 
-Vendor Class Identifier (VCI)
-Option 43 sub-option code
-Management IP address(es) of WLAN controller(s)

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless-mobility/wireless-lan-wlan/97066-dhcp-option-43-00.html

Comment: @RiSolver, you may want to provide a link to the admin guide in question if possible. First, this provides validity to your statement. Second, there may be different versions of the admin guide (for instance for different versions of the code) where the section you reference is on a different page.

Comment: Here you can find something about the DHCP options: http://dloads.infoblox.com/direct/appliance/NIOS/NIOS_AdminGuide_6.10.pdf page 803...